# Why is pyramidal structure observed in trisilylphosphine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, hybridization, erratum, pnictogen

Why does trisilylphosphine $\ce{P(SiH3)3}$ (ICSD Entry: [72676](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=72676), [[1](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270190009593)]) have a pyramidal structure while trisilylamine $\ce{N(SiH3)3}$ (ICSD Entry: [201428](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=201428), [[2](https://doi.org/10.1039/dt9840000563)]) is planar?

[image: Crystal structures of trisilylamine and trisilylphosphine]

I think since silicon has a *vacant* d-orbital, it would form a backbond, wherein phosphorus shares its lone pair, as is the case with trisilylamine. This would result in $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization, i.e. a trigonal *planar* structure.

However, the crystal structure confirms the pyramidal $\ce{P}$ atom, which is also preserved in the gas phase [[1](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270190009593)]:

> Although IR and Raman spectroscopic results (Davidson, Ebsworth,
> Sheldrick & Woodward, 1966) were consistent with trisilylphosphine being similar to trisilylamine in that the central atom was surrounded by a trigonal planar arrangement of $\ce{Si}$ atoms, electron diffraction studies (Beagley, Robiette & Sheldrick, 1968) established pyramidal geometry in the gas phase.
>
> […]
>
> The crystal structure of trisilylphosphine may be
> contrasted with those of trisilylamine and trimethylamine.
> As $\ce{N(SiH3)3}$ has a planar heavy-atom skeleton and concomitantly lacks a stereochemically active lone pair (Barrow & Ebsworth, 1984), the absence of discrete intermolecular $\ce{Si\bond{...}N}$ contacts — seen in solid dimethylsilylamine (Blake, Ebsworth & Welch, 1984a) and chlorosilyl-*N*,*N*-dimethylamine (Anderson, Blake, Cradock, Ebsworth, Rankin &
> Welch, 1986) — is unsurprising.
> Like $\ce{P(SiH3)3},$ trimethylamine is clearly pyramidal $[\angle \ce{CNC} = 110.40(7)^\circ]$ but the absence of vacant d orbitals on the $\ce{C}$ atoms removes the possibility of these acting as acceptors
> and the crystal comprises isolated molecules (Blake, Ebsworth & Welch, 1984b).

*J.D. Lee Concise Inorganic Chemistry* [3, p. 77] also specifically mentions that $\ce{P(SiH3)3}$ has a trigonal pyramidal structure:

> In case of $\ce{P(SiH3)3},$ the internuclear distance is large and $\ce{P}$ atom has its own vacant d orbital. Hence the tendency to donate lone pair is very less and it adopts pyramidal structure and $\ce{P}$ atom is $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized.

#### References

1. Blake, A. J.; Ebsworth, E. A. V.; Henderson, S. G. D. Structure of Trisilylphosphine, $\ce{P(SiH3)3},$ at $\pu{100 K}.$ *Acta Crystallogr C Cryst Struct Commun* **1991**, 47 (3), 486–489. DOI: [10.1107/S0108270190009593](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270190009593).
2. Barrow, M. J.; Ebsworth, E. A. V. Crystal and Molecular Structure of Trisilylamine at $\pu{115 K}.$ *J. Chem. Soc., Dalton Trans.* **1984**, No. 4, 563. DOI: [10.1039/dt9840000563](https://doi.org/10.1039/dt9840000563).
3. Sudarsan Guha. *J.D. Lee Concise Inorganic Chemistry, for JEE (Main & Advanced)*, 4th ed.; Wiley India Pvt. Ltd.: India, **2017** (reprint 2020). ISBN 978-81-265-9114-5.

Comment: also wikipedia explains the reasons for the geometry in P(CH3)3...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimethylphosphine. Could possibly extrapolate to the trisilyl

Comment: @lazarus98 but since Carbon doesn't have any vacant d orbitals being a second period element and nor any lone pairs while forming trimethylphosphine I am unable to explain the reason why backbonding doesn't take place in trisilyl since that _does_ have a vacant d orbital  and phosphorus has a lone pair that it can use up

Comment: @Substitute_Y The lone pair in phosphorus has mainly 3s character, therefore overlap with the 3d is likely poor due to differences in orbital energies. Therefore, back bonding is not significant for phosphorus.

Comment: Just read https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69568/hybridization-of-nitrogen-in-trisilylamine-sih33n instead of spawning some  "vacant d orbital" nonsense.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/when-to-consider-back-bonding-and-when-to-not-when-will-it-change-hybridisation

Comment: @Mithoron Nonsense?

Comment: @Lazarus98 Just read the linked answers. I dunno why anyone would even know some  trisilylphosphine exist at all, and still buy into stuff deprecated at least 30 years ago.

Comment: @Substitute_Y My previous explanationis is wrong. For the case of N(SiH3)3, although there is some amount of back bonding, it is not the dominate "driving force". Rather, polarization of the N-Si bond leads to a stronger electrostatic repulsion between -silyl groups that forces the geometry to be planar. Its not that the silicon d-orbital isn't involved in delocalization of the lone pair, its just that this is not what leads to the planar geometry. Nor is it the dominate mode of delocalization for the N lone pair.

Comment: Donating of the Nitrogen lone pair happens more through hyperconjugation to the silicon sigma * orbital.

Answer (score 1):

[image: trisilyl boron nitrogen and phosphorus]

Let us analyze the three cases:

1. $\ce{B(SiH3)3}$
2. $\ce{N(SiH3)3}$
3. $\ce{P(SiH3)3}$

We are going to look at the back-bonding aspect. It is expected that the structures will be more planer as the extent of back-bonding increases. In this case the $\ce{N(SiH3)3}$, $\ce{Si}$-$\ce{N}$-$\ce{Si}$ bond angle is 119.8 degrees. which is just 120 degrees meaning that the structure is, more or less, triangular planer.

## First Observations

### $\ce{B(SiH3)3}$

Boron has no lone-pairs to back-donate, or according to VSEPR theory, we expect it to be triangular planer, as predicted by *ab-initio* calculations.

### $\ce{N(SiH3)3}$

Nitrogen has a lone pair of electrons that can back-bond with silicon. In this case the $\ce{Si}$-$\ce{N}$-$\ce{Si}$ bond angle is 119.8 degrees.

### $\ce{P(SiH3)3}$

Phosphorous also has a lone pair of electrons that can back-bond with silicon. In this case the $\ce{Si}$-$\ce{P}$-$\ce{Si}$ bond angle is 101.8 degrees.

At RHF level of theory, not only is there more back-bonding in trisilylamine, it is close to triangular planer trisilylboron, or that the electorn pair is completely shared between $\ce{N}$ and silyl groups.

Back-bonding or absence of isolated p-orbitals on the central atom can lead to planarity.