Is there no diagonal relationship for carbon and phosphorus?
As per the rule and what we were taught in our school, 2nd-period elements show a diagonal relationship with similar properties.
For example, lithium shows similar properties with magnesium, and boron and silicon also possess this diagonal relation.
There seems to be no such diagonal relation for carbon, though.

I think there is.

I think these diagonal  relationships are a stretch. If you look hard enough you'll find some similarities, like, wherever you want.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/33009/9961

The diagonal relationships fall apart much more for nitrogen/sulfur. I can think of a lot of things that carbon and phosphorus have in common. I can't think of anything for nitrogen and sulfur other than that they are both nonmetals. Fluorine/argon is a joke.

This question is similar to: Diagonal relationships in the Periodic Table. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The famed diagonal relationships between second- and third-period elements is strongest for lithium-magnesium and weakens as we move across the Periodic Table from there.
One reason for this is that the $n=2$ valence shells of the second-period elements and the $n=3$ valence shells of the third-period elements differ in structure: the latter orbitals are generally more diffuse and have an extra radial node compared with the former. Regardless of any similarity in electronegativity that (let us say) carbon has with phosphorus, this difference in orbital structure is going to lead to differences in bonds containing a strong component from these orbitals.
With lithium and magnesium, this orbital-structure effect is diminished because, to the extent that these elements bond covalently at all, the electrons are strongly polarized towards the other atom; the differently structured lithium $n=2$ and magnesium $n=3$ orbitals contribute little to the bonding molecular orbitals. Thus for instance solid hydrides and fluorides of both elements are mostly ionic with the metals octahedrally coordinated. With carbon and phosphorus, the respective $n=2$ and $n=3$ valence shells figure more strongly into the bonding orbitals and we see very different bonding characteristics in (for instance) the hydrides and halides of these elements.

There is indeed a diagonal relationship between phosphorus and carbon.

Both carbon and phosphorus exhibit allotropes.
Both carbon and phosphorus show almost the same electronegativities.
Both form strong pi and sigma bonds.
Like carbon, phosphorus can also form triple bonds.

(Source)
And on this basis, many studies has been made on phosphorus chemistry. I want to highlight two cases:



An iconic diagonal relationship has long been recognized between carbon and phosphorus, especially in cases where element-element multiple bonding is present, such as diphosphorus ($\ce{P2}$) in which two phosphorus atoms are joined by a weak triple bond.
This diagonal relationship between phosphorus and carbon has set that expectation that the diphosphorus molecule should mimic the attributes of the hydrocarbon acetylene ($\ce{C2H2}$). For instance, both diphosphorus and acetylene react with other organic molecules through their pi-bonds, a type of covalent bond found in molecules with multiple bonding.
https://today.ucsd.edu/story/unstable-molecule-clicks-with-synthetic-strategy




A variety of analogies between the chemistry of carbon and phosphorus
are often related to their diagonal relationship in the Periodic Table
which also indicates the potential for phosphorus to adopt catenated
frameworks that exhibit the extent and diversity established for
hydrocarbons. However, development of hydrophosphorus frameworks is likely
impeded by the
relatively low P-P bond enthalpy ($\pu{P-P = 201 kJ/mol}$, cf. $\pu{C-C = 346 kJ/mol}$) in neutral compounds, and the facile reactivity of $\ce{P- 
H}$ bonds, relative to $\ce{C-H}$ bonds. We have recently demonstrated
that $\ce{P-P}$ bonded molecules possessing a cationic charge have a
$\ce{P-P}$ bond enthalpy
that is comparable to that of the $\ce{C-C}$ bond in neutral hydrocarbon
frameworks. While a variety of cationic catenated phosphorus frameworks
have been systematically synthesized and comprehensively characterized,
the extent and diversity of frameworks is still limited, even for short
chain systems.
2-Phosphino-1,3-diphosphonium Ions by Paul. A. Gray, Yuen-ying Carpenter, Neil Burford and Robert McDonald (link)




Both form strong pi and sigma bonds? P forms seriously lame bonds. You write yourself 201 vs 346 - this is a lot weaker.

Not only do they both exhibit multiple allotropes, but these allotropes have a larger variety of structures than any other two elements I can think of. Both can form covalent network solids (diamond and violet phosphorus), molecular allotropes (C60 and white phosphorus), and stacked 2D materials (graphite and black phosphorus).
